# ng-class is messing up with static and dynamic content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have introduced ng-repeat where static contents are already there. Its working properly. When i put ng-class and set the variable its not working. How to fix that issue and why its happening.

Click on each li. Its not working on dynamic elements.

Please find the code in fiddle.

```
<h3>FIFA Mactch Summary:</h3>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<ul>
<li ng-class='{"selectedClass":classHilight==1}' ng-click="filterNews(3);classHilight=1"> My static content 1</li>
<li ng-class='{"selectedClass":classHilight==2}' ng-click="filterNews(3);classHilight=2" > My static content 2</li>
<li ng-class='{"selectedClass":classHilight==3}' ng-click="filterNews(3);classHilight=3"> My static content 3</li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class='{"selectedClass":classHilight==item.id}' ng-click="filterNews(item.id);classHilight=item.id" >My Dynamic Content {{item.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gowthambsvg/2m41tjq9/

Comment: Value of `model` is not updated when  `ng-repeat`  is used, Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/2m41tjq9/1/

Comment: @RayonDabre, might want to put it as an answer :)

Comment: Thank you @RayonDabre. What is the issue when we directly handling on html itself.

Comment: @JeremyRajan, Will not be able to put valid reason to defend my point ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is said that, *You must always have `.` in your model.*

In ng-repeat `classHilgiht` doesn't refer to the scope variable `classHilight`. It creates its own `scope` for each item in `ng-repeat`. It does not refer to `classHilight`. But when `classHilight` is used as `key` of `test` object, object inherits the property from the child scope of the `ng-repeat` directive.

Try this:

```js
var m = [{
  id: 4
}, {
  id: 5
}, {
  id: 6
}];

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.test = {};
  $scope.items = m;

  $scope.setClass = function() {

  }
}
```

```css
.selectedClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h3>FIFA Mactch Summary:</h3>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-class='{"selectedClass":test.classHilight==1}' ng-click="test.classHilight=1">My static content 1</li>
    <li ng-class='{"selectedClass":test.classHilight==2}' ng-click="test.classHilight=2">My static content 2</li>
    <li ng-class='{"selectedClass":test.classHilight==3}' ng-click="test.classHilight=3">My static content 3</li>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class='{"selectedClass":test.classHilight==item.id}' ng-click="test.classHilight=item.id">My Dynamic Content {{item.id}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/2m41tjq9/4/)

**Edit:** One can not say `classHilight` is not updated in `ng-repeat`, it is being updated but within its own scope. [[Ref](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/2m41tjq9/9/)]

Comment: " It is said that, You must always have . in your model. " . The sentence itself clarified my doubts. Thank you